# Project Tango Unity app crashes iff there are two scene Cameras

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Making an area-aware Unity app on Tango, and it works fine until I add another camera. It uses an ADF for location awareness, and the default AR Camera prefab. So it shows what the device's camera sees. Fine. Now I want to add a mini-map in the upper corner. Simply adding another camera will cause the app to crash. I tried:
- perspective vs orthog
- render to texture
- various 'clear' flags
- checked my layers
- no culling or anything fancy
It's simple. If I enable the camera, it crashes. If I disable the camera, it works.

Does anyone have any insights into this?

Thanks

Comment: what's the crash log? `adb logcat`

Comment: I'll try to get one, but while it's crashing, nothing is added. Which is to say, if at startup I Debug.Log("Starting"); and nothing else, that's the last thing I'll see in the log until it's crashed.

Comment: I take it back, I was using -s Unity on logcat. Not doing that, another story:

Comment: Tried pasting in logcat dump, it didn't 'take' editing OP

Comment: Hi Dave, I am not sure what you mean.. adb logcat should just be a terminal output, you can write it to a file as well..

Comment: Hi Jason. I mean, when I inserted it into this post, the linefeeds were all wrong, became very hard to read. Are you saying I should attache it as a file instead?